# YouTube API "Failed to start the resumable upload (HTTP 401..." error after change of ownership of channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth

I have a script that uploads videos, previously uploaded to our server, to YouTube. Before I had been getting the following error:

```
Failed to start the resumable upload (HTTP 401: youtube.header, Unauthorized)
```

I found out that the account we were trying to upload to didn't have it's own YouTube channel. The previous version of the software uploaded to a different account's channel. However, now we have opted to have a single account where our Google Analytics and YouTube channel is.

So, to ensure that the script was working, on the account that didn't have a channel but the account we wanted to use for analytics and YouTube channel, but at this stage didn't have a channel yet, I created a test channel and using my script was now able to upload videos to the YouTube. The error from before was gone.

Now that we had a working script that was uploading to YouTube, just the wrong channel, we decided to change the ownership of the desired channel to the single account (single account that has the analytics and oauth keys). First, I removed the test channel. Then we logged into the owner of the desired channel and changed the ownership to the single account we want to use via the managers page. This all appeared to happen instantly.

Now when I ran the script, I got the same error as before. I was kinda expecting this as it was not yet the default channel. So, I set the transferred channel as the default account. Now when I click on My channel, instead of prompting me to create a new channel, it displays the transferred account - great. I thought the script would upload now, as it had done once I'd created the test account, but I still get the same error:

```
Failed to start the resumable upload (HTTP 401: youtube.header, Unauthorized)
```

By the way, it was only an hour ago we transferred the channel but it seems that's all went through (as in, the new owner can now manage managers of that channel) .. I'll keep checking the script as long as it's not working encase it's just a delay in some aspects of the change to set in place.

Also, I'm considering creating new OAuth keys as the keys were created before the transfer, if that matters, which I have my doubts. I don't suspect it's an issue with our code anyway, I think things just aren't setup correctly when the new owner and transferred account, I'm just not sure what though.

UPDATE:

Does the channel need to be linked to a Google+ "profile", not "page"? I notice that the transferred channel is currently linked to a "page" even though it all owned by the same account.

Comment: I see someone has voted that this be closed. Can you please give some feedback as to why it is in the wrong place, or what the issue is, so that I can post correctly next time. According to this Google page, Stack Overflow is the correct place to ask - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support "Google engineers monitor and answer questions with the youtube-api, youtube-data-api, and youtube-v3-api tags." Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you have the same issue that I have. But I have a site that can upload a video to a client's YouTube account. It worked perfectly for me, but for other users we got the same error as you do:

> Failed to start the resumable upload (HTTP 401: youtube.header, Unauthorized)

I found the resolution for me. If a new YouTube user tries to do an upload and they don't have a "My channel" for their account, they get that error. Once they have created a channel, the video upload works.